# How do I create an array of icons from the public folder so that I can map them in my nextjs 13 app?

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-image

I have a nextjs 13.4 app. Inside the app's public folder I have put .svg icons. I wanted to create an array of objects which consists a title and an icon. I tried to import the icons to the component and add it to the array, then map through the array. But I don't understand how this works. I used to import and use icons from the likes of materialui which is a js code. I have never used actual images/icons before. I also have tried importing and using it with an <Image />  element which works perfectly fine. But what I am struggling with is that I don't know how to create an array with these icons.

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import busIcon from '../public/busIcon.svg'


const page = () => {

  const Menus = [
    { title: "Bus", icon: busIcon },
    { title: "Route", icon: "route.svg" },
    { title: "Schedule", icon: "schedule.svg" },
    { title: "Booking", icon: "booking.svg" },
    { title: "Ticketing", icon: "ticketing.svg" },
    { title: "Check-in", icon: "check-in.svg" },
    { title: "Departure", icon: "departure.svg" },
    { title: "Tracking", icon: "tracking.svg" },
    { title: "Finance", icon: "finance.svg" },
    { title: "Reports", icon: "reports.svg" },
    { title: "Manage User", icon: "manage user.svg" },
    { title: "Help", icon: "help.svg" },
    { title: "Logout", icon: "" },

  ]


  return (
    <div className='bg-light-gray h-screen flex'>

      <div className="bg-light-white w-72 p-5 pt-8">
        <h1 className='text-dark-green text-2xl origin-left font-medium '>Dashboard</h1>
        <div>
          <ul className='pt-2'>
            {Menus.map((menu, index) => (
              <>
                <li key={index} className='text-dark-green text-sm flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-light-gray rounded-md'>
                  <span className='text-2xl block float-left'>
                    <Image src={busIcon} alt='bus Icon' />
                  </span>
                  <span className='text-base font-medium flex-1'>{menu.title}</span>
                </li>
              </>
            ))}

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>

        <Image src={busIcon} alt='bus icon' />
        hello JAFA
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default page;
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need import image or svg just set your address on your array :

```
  const Menus = [
    { title: "Bus", icon:" ../busIcon.svg"},
  ]
```

note : Make sure you enter the correct address for image or icons

then in map method you can use your icon or image  :

```
<image src={icon} alt='bus Icon' />
```

i hope this help .

Comment: thanks Mohsen, but it doesn't seem to work. I mean I tried setting the address in the array and it returns an error saying 'expression expected' right at the beginning of the address.

Comment: i think 'expression expected' error about invalid syntax for array . this mean you are try something for array  , array cant know that

Comment: Yup, that’s my guess but I couldn’t find the right syntax.

Comment: try this  , create one array , with 3 object , and try maping , they object just 2 peroperty , name and id , like this : 

const testArray = [ {id:1 , name:"testOne"} , {id:2 , name:"testTwo"} , {id:3 , name:"testThree"}] , 

then if you are get result i'am not sure but i think this have a proplem , with empty icon , 

 { title: "Logout", icon: "" },

Comment: thank you Mosen, It finally worked for me and I will put the code next. Actually the logout part was not the problem it was the way I accessed and mapped the icons which had a problem. check out my next comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got to know how it works. here is the code that worked for me to map the title and the icons.

```js
const page = () => {
  const Menus = [
    { title: "Bus", icon: "/Icons.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Route", icon: "/routeIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Schedule", icon: "/scheduleIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Booking", icon: "/bookingIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Ticketing", icon: "/ticketingIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Check-in", icon: "/check-inIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Departure", icon: "/departureIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Tracking", icon: "/trackingIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Finance", icon: "/financeIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Reports", icon: "/reportsIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Manage User", icon: "/manageUserIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Help", icon: "/helpIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },
    { title: "Logout", icon: "/logoutIcon.svg", width: 30, height: 30 },

  ]



  return (
    <>

    ...
          <div>
            <ul className='pt-2'>
              {Menus.map((menu, index) => (
                <>
                  <li key={index} className='text-dark-green text-sm flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-light-gray rounded-md'>
                    <span className='text-2xl block float-left text-dark-green'> 
                      <Image
                        src={menu.icon}
                        alt={menu.title}
                        width={menu.width}
                        height={menu.height}
                      />
                    </span>
                    <span className='text-base font-medium flex-1'>{menu.title}</span>
                  </li>
                </>
              ))}

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkbOX.png)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best approach as I am also a beginner. I brought up the question and Mohsen tried to help me with the answer he provided in the comments. Using his method, I got the icons broken (the way image places look when the data is not fully loaded or slow connection kind of thing to show it is an image). then I was trying different ways I came across and finally it worked for me when I created the object array of Menus as I attached above. meaning, to render the images from the public folder, it is done as `{icon: "/icons.svg"}` rather than  `{icon: "../icons.svg"}`.